# ZAP Report is saying SQL injection

Tags: security, sql-injection, penetration-testing, burp, penetration-tools

I performed a scan through ZAP, it is showing SQL injection in report, However I am not able to regenerate it manually. 
Can someone guide me ?

I tried to post the same request in "Postman" but its saying "Please provide token". 
Click here to see image[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7CnC.png)

Answer (score 1):

It may be a false positive. Generated report we need find it.